# Disable Submit button once database field is filled

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have created a form with submit button. If "price" for a particular product is already filled then the Submit button must be disabled:

[image]

**Code Php**

```
<?php
  $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db_name="ge";

    $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("Your Connection is in error");
  $sql="SELECT pname,catogery,email FROM quetation WHERE catogery = '$catogery'";

    $results=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $count=mysqli_num_rows($results);
    if($count == 0) {
        echo "<font color=\"#0000\"><h1 align=\"center\">No details found</h1></font>";
    } else {
        $resource=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        echo "<font color=\"#000000\">
        <h2 align=\"center\"></h2>
        <table align=\"center\" border=\"1\" width=\"50%\">
            <tr>
                <td><b>ProdName</b></td>
                <td><b>Catogery</b></td>
                <td><b>Price</b></td>
           </tr> ";
      while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($resource)) {
                echo "
            <div class=\"row\">
            <div class=\"input-field col s12\">
            <tr>
              <td>".$result[0]."</td>
              <td>".$result[1]."</td>
              <td>
                   <form name=\"abc\" methos=\"post\" action=\"postprice.php\">
                        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\">
                  </form>
               </td>
               </div>
               </div>
            </tr>";
          } echo "</table></font>";
    }
?>
```

**Only once price should be entered if already entered then send button should be disabled**

Whenever I load this page it should check the database and if price value is filled then it should disable the send button.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: check the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code in the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="this.disabled=true;">
```

This will disable the button after clicking the submit button. Hope it helps you.

PLz try this code, hope it will work.

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db_name="ge";

    $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("Your Connection is in error");




    $sql="SELECT pname,catogery,email,price FROM quetation WHERE catogery = '$catogery'";

    $results=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($results);
    if($count == 0)
    {
            echo "<font color=\"#0000\"><h1 align=\"center\">No details found</h1></font>";
    }
    else
    {
       $resource=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       echo "<font color=\"#000000\">
              <h2 align=\"center\"></h2>

            <table align=\"center\" border=\"1\" width=\"50%\">
            <tr>
            <td><b>ProdName</b></td>
            <td><b>Catogery</b></td>
            <td><b>Price</b></td>

</tr> ";

    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($resource))
        {
        echo "

            <div class=\"row\">
    <div class=\"input-field col s12\">
<tr>
        <td>".$result[0]."</td>
        <td>".$result[1]."</td>
    <td><form name=\"abc\" methos=\"post\" action=\"postprice.php\">";
    if($result[3]==''){
     echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\" onClick='this.disabled=true;'>";
    } else {
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\" disabled>";
    } 
    echo "</td>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
        </tr>";
        }echo "</table></font>";
        }

?>
```

Comment: It will..but next time when i load this page again,it will show

Comment: Then you need to add price in the query and check if Not empty then add the below code else do the given code. disabled

Comment: can u send the code? how to add onclick if query contains value??

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

first you will check in database product price is available or not if price is available then set the variable 0 for not available or 1 for available;